# Translate a unimodular distribution so as to minimize its total-variation distance to another unimodular distribution

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

**Definition.** *A function $f:\mathbb R^d \rightarrow [0,1]$ is called a unimodular density function if*

- *$\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)dx=1$.*
- *$f$ is quasiconcave.*
- *$f$ has a unique maximum point $m_f \in \mathbb R^d$ called the mode of $f$.*

Let $f_1,f_2:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be unimodular density functions. For $v \in \mathbb R^d$, let
$$
I(v) := \int_{\mathbb R^d}\min(f_1(x),f_2(x-v))dx = \int_{\mathbb R^d}\min(f_1(x-v),f_2(x))dx,
$$
be the area enclosed by the densities $f_1$, $f_2(\cdot-v)$ and the coordinate axes in $\mathbb R^d$.

> **Question 1.** For $r \ge 0$, compute / describe the maximizers $v^*$ of $I(v)$ for $v \in \mathbb B_d(0; r) := \{ v \in \mathbb R^d \mid \|v\| \le r\}$.
>
> **Question 2.** Same question with the additional informaiton that $r < \|m_{f_1}-m_{f_2}\|$.

**What I'm after.** *Of crouse, such questions will certainly not have a definitive answers in general, so I'm happy to hear interesting ideas on the problem (in the form of comments, or full posts, which will be duely upvoted, of course). For example, something which reduces the search for the optimizers $v^*$ to a tractable convex optimization problem (e.g projection onto a simple convex set, etc.) will already be helpful. One may assume some moment conditions on the $f_j$'s (e.g finite variance, sub-Gaussian, etc.), and then outline a solution concept / strategy in that case.*

### Statistical intepretation

Let $P_j$ be the probability distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ with density $f_j$ and for $v \in \mathbb R^d$, let $P_j - v$ be the probability distribution with density $f_j(\cdot - v)$. That is, if $X_j$ is a random variable with distribution $P_j$, then $P_j - v$ is the distribution of $X-v$. Then, the [total-variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between $P_1$ and $P_2-v$ is given by $$
TV(P_1, P_2-v) = 1 - I(v)
.
$$

Thus, **Questions 1 & 2** ask to find a global translation $v \in \mathbb R^d$ with norm at most $r$ such that the total variation distance between $P_1$ and $P_2 - v$ is minimized.

## Special cases

Let me present a few worked examples to get the ball rolling. Let $\Delta := m_2-m_1 \in \mathbb R^d$.

### Gaussians of same shape

If $f_j$ is the density of $d$-dimensional Gaussian with mean $m_j$ and covariance $\Sigma$, then one can show that

$$
TV(P_1,P_2-v) = TV(\mathcal N(m_1,\Sigma),\mathcal N(m_2-v,\sigma)) = 2\Phi(\|v-\Delta\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}/2)-1,
$$

Thus, $\arg\max_{\|v\| \le r}I(v) = \arg\min_{\|v\| \le r} \|v-\Delta\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}$, which can be identified with projection onto an ellipsoid. If in particular the covariance matrix is diagonal, then things are reduced to projecting onto an $L_2$ ball, and the optimal translation is given analytically by
$v^* = \dfrac{r\Delta}{\max(r, \|\Delta\|)}$.

### Exponential families

Similar analysis as above. Problem can be approximated with KL divergence using *Pinker's inequality*, and then KL can be computed analytically for expo families), and then computation of $v^*$ is reduced to a tractable convex optimization problem.

### Symmetric 1D unimodular distributions of shape "shape" and "scale"

If $F$ is the CDF for the centralized distribution $P_1-m_1$, then a simple symmetry argument reveals that $TV(P_1,P_1-v) = 2F(|v-\Delta|)-1$ and so $v^* = \arg\max_{|v| \le r}2F(|v-\Delta|) - 1$
It's easy to compute that $v^* = \dfrac{r\Delta}{\max(r, |\Delta|)}$.

### Location-scale families

Similar to previous case...

Comment: This is interesting, but how could a general answer look like if there is no further information available on the functions $f_1, f_2$? What about some kind of series in the parameters of the distribution? ie the first term will attempt to overlay the two modes, the second term corrects using the co-variance, the third corrects using skewdness, the fourth using kurtosis etc...

Comment: @s.harp Indeed, such a question will certainly not have a definitive solution, so I'm happy to hear interesting ideas on the problem (in the form of comments, or full posts, which will be duely upvoted, of course). For example, something which reduces the the optimization problem into a tractable convex optimization problem (e.g projection unto convex set, etc.) will already be helpful. If it helps, you can assume some moment condition on the $f_j$'s (e.g finite variance, sub-Gaussian, etc.), and then outline a solution concept in that case (I've added some worked examples in the question).

Comment: Also, I'd be interested in hearing more about your "series expansion" idea. Wee both agree that intuitively, the optimal translation should be something like $v^*=m_1-m_2+\text{correction terms}$.